# Disabling buttons in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have three fragments. One of them can dynamically replaced with another fragment. How can I disable buttons in this "dynamical" fragment. Disabling buttons of the other fragments funtctions. When I compile my App, I get a java.lang.NullPointerException.

```
//MainActivity
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

```
public static Button Button_1;
public static Button Button_2;

Block fragment;

...

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
...
Button_1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button_2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
...
fragment = (Block) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.block_frag);
...
}
```

...
}

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

switch(view.getId()) {
    ...
    case R.id.radioButton4:
    {

    Button_1.setEnabled(false);
    Button_2.setEnabled(false);
            fragment.Button_3.setEnabled(false);
            fragment.Button_4.setEnabled(false);

    break;
        }
        case R.id.radioButton5:
        {
    ...
```

}

//block_frag:

public class Block extends Fragment{

`public Button Button_3;
public Button Button_4;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Button_3=(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button_4=(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.button4);`

...
}

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Override 
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Button_3=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button3);
    }
```

Yes it should be inside fragment

Comment: Should these codelines in the fragment-module be inserted? And if it is so, I get errors by doing so. First of all @Override-snippet isn' t accepted. And when I use Bundle savedInstanceState as parameter and additonally super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) in the first line of the code, I get the error: SuperNotCalledException. I guess that in the last case, it has another constructor to be called.

Comment: First of all I thank you for your answers. I adapted the code after your advice. But I get a java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.program.MainActivity.onRadioButtonClicked(MainActivity.java:...

Comment: I wrote also the code for Button_4. I also want to add a further error-code. The LogCat says before the error java.lang.NullPointerException: ...Caused by java.lang.reflect.InnVocationTargetException...

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my fault. The code: `code` (fragment = (Block) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.block_frag)), should be in the method `code` (public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view)) . Thanks Greensy for your help.